# Phonegap / Ionic augmented reality

Tags: ionic-framework, augmented-reality, phonegap

I've been Googling and Googling for an augmented reality plugin to use for my app but I keep returning to Wikitude, which costs a fortune (at least, at this moment). So I'm reaching out to you.

I'm looking for an AR plugin that can display an image onto a marker/placeholder. If it is possible to play a video as well that would be great but its not mandatory.

Have you been at this point before? Which plugin did you choose and why?
Thanks for reading and taking your time to respond.

Comment: I know this is not a real plugin but a nice starter i think - https://market.ionicframework.com/starters/wikitude-ionic-3-starter-app

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ar you should be able to port this.